# Can I use OMPL for path planning/tutorial

Tags: ros, ompl-planning

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I want to use the OMPL ros package to do some motion planning with a create and hokuyo laser scanner. But the ompl_ros_interface tutorial seems completely focused on moving a robotic arm. Is there a good place to start? I've been reading the OMPL's website tutorials as well.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66833/can-i-use-ompl-for-path-planning/tutorial/) by [Challen](https://answers.ros.org/users/5350/challen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-07-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there, are you doing motion planning for a vehicle or something that moves in 2D?
You don't need OMPL to achieve so, the [ROS navigation stack](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation) does that for you with more time optimized algorithms.
A great example of that is the [Turtlebot who navigates in a known environment](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_navigation/Tutorials/indigo/Autonomously%20navigate%20in%20a%20known%20map) (it can also be an unknown environment so no worries.)

You can check how it works in this youtube video: https://youtu.be/PJH2oMeSjFQ

---

Originally posted by [bpinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28465/bpinaya/) with karma: 700 on 2017-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0